# How to structure if...else statement to return true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Full code https://codepen.io/3noki/pen/xjyErQ

```
function checkForMatch() {
  if ( $(openedCardsList[0]).is(openedCardsList[1]) ) {
  $(openedCardsList[0]).removeClass('open show').addClass('match');
  $(openedCardsList[1]).toggleClass('open show');
  $(openedCardsList[1]).toggleClass('match');
  $(openedCardsList) = [];
  }

  else {unFlip()}
}
```

This code currently only returns false values, I would like to know how to structure this in either pure DOM or pure jquery format to be able to return a true value.

```
openedCardsList[0]===openedCardsList[1]
```

Has not returned true either

When the card at array 0 and 1 are the same I want this value to be returned true.

Comment: There is no `return` at all. Really not clear what you are asking

Comment: When two cards are open and they match, this should be returned true, but this is returning false, trying to use a.is(b) hasn't worked either.

Comment: What property or properties of the cards should be compared for them to be considered to be matching?

Comment: If you look at the full code on codepen.io, the cardsList shows the full array with background images. It's passed to the "i" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking/matching against the (FontAwesome) icon `class` names?

So when creating the card (or generating its HTML), you'd add `fa` to the element's "data" (using `jQuery.data()`), like this:

```
function createCardHTML() {
  symbol = cards.children("i");
  symbol.each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).addClass(cardsList[index])
      // If the icon's class name is `fa-diamond`, `$(item).data('fa')` would be `diamond`.
      .data('fa', cardsList[index].substring(3)); // <- here's the data
  });
  return symbol;
}
```

And then, in `checkForMatch()`:

```
var b = $('i.fa', openedCardsList[0]).data('fa');
var c = $('i.fa', openedCardsList[1]).data('fa');
var eq = ( b && c && b === c );
```

[**Demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjVQob?editors=0011)

Comment: *you'd add `fa` to the element's "data"* - I was referring to the `i` element inside the card.

Comment: This worked perfectly, could I also ask if there is a way to do this in pure Javascript?

Comment: Yes. **Option 1**: Use `Element.dataset` in place of `jQuery.data()`, and `Element.querySelector()` to find the `i.fa` element *in the card*. Try it here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzQdeO/left?editors=0011 (see the code marked with `// In vanilla JS`). **Option 2**: Same like Option 1 actually, except use `Element.setAttribute()` and `Element.getAttribute()` instead of direct access to `Element.dataset`; see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxQvzy/left?editors=0011